# How to change url path with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want with `htaccess` change **example.com/course.php?name=php-advanced** to **example.com/course/php-advanced**

Also, change **example.com/contact.php** to **example.com/contact**

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^course/(.*)$ course.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```